# How to rotate a rectangle in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hi guys, I am working on an assignment where I need to draw an image of an emoticon face.

```
function sadFace() {
//Drawing the sad face
context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)" //Drawing the face in yellow colour
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.arc(300,300,200,0,Math.PI*4,true);
    context.fill();
context.stroke();
//Left Eyebrow
context.beginPath();            
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.rect(170,180,90,15);
    context.fill();
context.stroke();
```

This is my current code. How can I rotate the 'eyebrow' of the image firstly, and also rotate the eyebrow without rotating the whole image? Thanks!

Comment: Paste the code, not an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use affine transformation, like rotation, translation, scale.
First save the current context

```
context.save()
```

Set rotation and translation [see document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate)

Restore the state

```
context.restore()
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)" //Drawing the face in yellow colour
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.arc(300,300,200,0,Math.PI*4,true);
    context.fill();
context.stroke();
//Left Eyebrow
context.save();
context.translate(210, 188);
context.rotate(30 * Math.PI / 180);
context.beginPath();            
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.rect(-45,-8,90,15);
    context.fill();
context.stroke();
context.restore();

context.save();
context.translate(380, 188);
context.rotate(-30 * Math.PI / 180);
context.beginPath();            
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.rect(-45,-8,90,15);
    context.fill();
context.stroke();
context.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" />
```

**Explanation:**

Since rotating is rotate around the coordinator (O (0, 0), we need to `translate` first to the position we want to draw:

```
context.translate(eyeBrowX, eyeBrowY); // eyebrow position here
```

Then do a `rotation`:

```
context.rotate(angleInRadian);
```

Then draw the rectangle so that the center of the rectangle is O (0, 0) - then it would rotate around its center.

```
context.beginPath();            
context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
context.rect(-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
context.fill();
context.stroke();
```

Comment: Right, I did try to do that but it ended up rotating the whole image and it kept printing the image in a circle?

                            context.beginPath();
                                context.save();
                                context.rotate(30*Math.PI/180);
                                context.translate(30*4,2);
                                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                                context.rect(170,180,90,15);
                                context.fill();
                            context.stroke();


This was the code I used

Comment: Add details explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Why did you use negative values for context.rect tho?

Comment: I have updated in the explanation, you need to draw the rectangle so that its center is (0, 0), then it will rotate around the center. Since you have translated to eyeBrowX, eyeBrowY, the center will be at that position.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been of great help! :)

Comment: If you feel the answer helps, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to rotate anything. Instead of creating `rect` just use lines to draw the eyebrows. Tell the line to go get drawn in a diagonal path like this

```js
  let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)" //Drawing the face in yellow colour
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.arc(300,300,200,0,Math.PI*4,true);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
  //Left Eyebrow
  context.beginPath();            
  context.moveTo(170,180);
  context.lineTo(260,195);
  context.lineWidth = 10
  context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
```

```html
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

In this way you don't need to save the context. By the way the `canvas` does not allow you to change things individually. You need to clear and redraw. (that how it works for animations for example). If you want more control, and modify things individually you need a rendering library like `Pixi.js`

Comment: Would this be an easier way compared to rectangle? As I would need to add animations later e.g: raise eyebrow upon clicking

Comment: @SamuelFung as I said, when animating you need to clear and redraw in the canvas inside of an animation loop (`requestAnimationFrame `). if you want more control I recommend pixi.js